# Module not found: Can't resolve in React

Tags: reactjs

I know that this question is repeated but I can't solve the issue with any of the published answers.

I'm getting the error below... and I don't see any issue in the code

```
./src/containers/navBarContainer/NavBarContainer.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '.../components/navBar/NavBar' in 'C:\Users\acanonicco001\Documents\CoderHouse\rjs\desafios-coder\src\containers\navBarContainer'
```

Comment: You need to import `NavBarContainer.js` file, if still not solved, then can you share your code!

Comment: probably there are something wrong with: 1) your import name or path; 2) your file name; 3) your folder name or structure. or even just cache. you need to provide more information

Comment: print your folder structure and the full content of the file that you're importing in it (if you are importing at all). also, make sure that this file are being exported correctly (`export` vs `export default`)

Answer (score 3):

You almost certainly meant to put `../` instead of `.../`.

[`../` indicates moving one folder up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59605). I don't know that `.../` actually has a defined meaning.